# service docker start fails (daemon is not a docker command)

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, upstart

I have a problem after I have tried to restart docker. Since then,
service docker start returns "start: Job failed to start".

This may have started once I have changed docker.conf. I have tried to reupload it using the command

```
wget -O /etc/init/docker.conf https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/docker/master/contrib/init/upstart/docker.conf
```

however, I was not lucky to fix this.

cat /var/log/upstart/docker.log returns:

```
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
docker: 'daemon' is not a docker command. See 'docker --help'.
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
docker: 'daemon' is not a docker command. See 'docker --help'.
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
docker: 'daemon' is not a docker command. See 'docker --help'.
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely have an old version of docker installed; the `docker daemon` subcommand was [added in docker 1.8](https://docs.docker.com/engine/deprecated/#old-command-line-options). Before that, the daemon was started using the `-d` / `--daemon` option (`docker -d`).

The version of the upstart-configuration you downloaded is intended for the *current* docker release; for older versions of docker, be sure to download the version that matches the version you've installed, for example; 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/docker/v1.7.1/contrib/init/upstart/docker.conf

I would suggest to upgrade to a more recent version of docker, because versions older than 1.8 are now getting quite old (in Docker terms)

Comment: thank you, saved me a lot of time. You are absolutely correct :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after upgrade to docker 19.03.5, I got this error.
When starting manually the `/usr/bin/dockerd` all works but via `systemctl start docker` it fails.

Looking at `journalctl -xe` I found the log:

```
docker: 'daemon' is not a docker command.
```

But the `docker.service` file was right, starting `/usr/bin/dockerd`.

I spent a time to figure out that the previous installation had a configuration file in: `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf` that replace the docker daemon start command(`/usr/bin/dockerd`) with other deprecated syntax.

In this case you can remove the `override.conf` file to allow docker start:

```
rm /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start docker
```

Hope it helps